# Loading new views from nav bar into a common div

Tags: java, jquery, html, angularjs, web-applications

I am building a basic html/java based web-application where I want all the different views to be loaded in the same div as and when the view is selected through the nav-bar.

So, the structure of the index.html would be -

```
    <div id="navDiv"></div>
    <div id="contentDiv"></div>
```

Now, I'm able to achieve this using jQuery.load(). The ui looks nice, the navbar only loads once. But the issue is, the back-button doesn't work. The load() function doesn't update the browser routing and history. How should I proceed?

I can use  to add the nav-bar in every page but the whole page would load every time instead of just the contentDiv.

I tried angular routeProvider through a sample project. It seems to get the job done, but I am not familiar with angular to completely build my application using it. Can I use it use it for only for the purpose of routing?

I don't want to use Apache Tiles or other template frameworks.

Please guide me on this.

Comment: You are describing how angular routers work. There are lots of tutorials around for the various routers

Comment: I'd suggest using angular ui-routers for routing